# Generalized logistic model, sometimes with a bump

Tags: r, model-selection, model, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to fit a generalized sigmoidal function with a bump which is a Gaussian kernel to some data. My model is of the form $y\sim f(t)+\epsilon$ where $f$ is the function:
$$
f(t) = A + \frac{K}{1+e^{-B(t-m_1)}} + Me^{\frac{-(x-m_2)^2}{2c^2}}
$$
All these parameters have some interpretational value which will be used for further analysis. But there is one problem. The bump is not always present in the data.

The following two images show some data, with a bump and without a bump. In the case of no bump I have only fitted the sigmoidal part of the function.

[image: Fit with bump]

[image: No bump]

I am trying to find a way to select the right model, i.e. only the sigmoid or the sigmoid with a bump.

There are several problems that I have run into. I am using R and the nls package. Sometimes when I fit the full model where there is no bump, then it is like the bump is only "trying" to make the fit slightly better. This can be seen in the following figure where I plot only the sigmoidal part of the full fit in red and the full model in blue (These are parameters from one fit with the full model).

[image: Fail with full model]

My first idea was to fit the full model and check whether the parameter $M$ (*which is the coefficient for the bump term*) is significantly different from zero or not. This does not seem to work in the cases where the bump is trying to compensate for something else, i.e. the $p$-value is on the same scale as for the parameter $M$ from the fitted model in the first figure.

I was also thinking about using a model selection criterion like AIC or BIC, but I am not sure if that will be a good idea, the selection tends to go for the more complex model.

I feel like I need to choose another candidate for the bump part of the model or maybe not go with the bump and try some kind of a decay function that makes the sigmoidal part drop down after the bump.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?